What kinds of votes in Congress are by secret ballot?
I was listening to "The Rest is Politics - US edition", where to paraphrase one of the hosts:

"Well, you see this shows that when they are on secret ballot, the Senate can stand up to Trump.  They voted for Thune (as Senate Leader), rather than Rick Scott as Trump wanted."

This got me to wonder.  There are sites where voters can check how their Congress person voted on motion X, Y or Z, so most votes are not anonymous.  (Ex: GovTrack.us)
Under what conditions do members of the Senate or the House cast their votes in secret ballots?  Electing a leader seems like an internal procedural concern and it seems Congress has a large latitude in how it runs those things, but are there are other circumstances where voting remains secret?

It may be in https://www.rules.senate.gov/rules-of-the-senate or in https://rules.house.gov/resources and of course all party specific votes may be secret, but they aren't really votes of the whole House or Senate, so may not count.

Thune is only the Senate majority leader and wasn't voted into this by the whole Senate only by GOP Senators. Is this included in the question?
